# Why do you use the word "into" in the next sentence?

Tags: syntax

1 the money or valuables that a player must hazard in order to buy "into" a gambling game or make a bet.

I think the word "in" would be more suitable as the word "into" implies direction par excellence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Into is a preposition of motion and change of state.

In this case to buy "into" a gambling game or make a bet. = to buy [in order to buy your way] "into" (i.e. to enter) a gambling game or make a bet.

Merriam Webster:

> **into** preposition
>
> **1 —used as a function word to indicate entry, introduction, insertion, superposition, or inclusion** *"He came into the house." "They enter into an alliance."*
>
> 2 : in the direction of looking into the sun
>
> 3 : to a position of contact with : against ran into a wall
>
> 4a : to the state, condition, or form of got into trouble
>
> 4b : to the occupation, action, or possession of go into farming

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please also tell me if to your native ears, the way I used the phrase "par excellence" in this very context is correct?